# WebApi: */* media type handling

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In my application I'm making some javascript requests to my Api Controllers to get some html formatted strings. When those requests are made with `Accept: */*` HTTP header (jQuery `$.get` method), so by default `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` is used and the data is returned with `Content-Type: application/json` in JSON format.

What I would like is to handle `*/*` requests as `text/html`. So I tried to create a custom `MediaTypeFormatter` that supports `*/*` media type, but it gives me the following error

> The 'MediaTypeHeaderValue' of `*/*` cannot be used as a supported
>   media type because it is a media range.`

Alternatively I could always provide correct expected data types in my requests, but I'm curious if there's a way to handle `*/*` media types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The above behavior is due to the following:

The default con-neg algorithm in Web API has the following **precedence order** of choosing the formatter for response:

1. Formatter match based on Media Type Mapping.
2. Formatter match based on Request Accept header's media type.
3. Formatter match based on Request Content-Type header's media type.
4. Formatter match based on if it can serialize the response data’s Type.

Now, JsonMediaTypeFormatter comes with a built-in media type mapping called XmlHttpRequestHeaderMapping which inspects an incoming request and sees if the request has the header `x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest` and also if there is no accept header or if the Accept header is only having `*/*`.

Since your request is mostly probably looking like below, according to the precedence order JsonMediaTypeFormatter is chosen as the one writing the response:

`GET /api/something

Accept: */*

x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest`

A solution for your issue would be is to explicitly ask for "text/html" as this is what you are expecting.

`GET /api/something

Accept: text/html

x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest`

Couple of very old blog posts about Content negotiation that I wrote:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/02/25/content-negotiation-in-asp-net-mvc4-web-api-beta-part-1.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/02/27/content-negotiation-in-asp-net-mvc4-web-api-beta-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Great question.

You can't set `*/*` to be a supported media type, but what you can do is set your formatter to be the first one. Web API will pick the first formatter in the formatter collection that can write out the type if there is no Accept header or if the Accept header is `*/*`.

So you'd want to configure your Web API like this:

```cs
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new MyHtmlFormatter());
```

Comment: that was my first thought, but for some reason `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` gets called first anyways. My formatter only gets called when expected data type is set to `text/html` in my requests.

Comment: JsonMediaTypeFormatter has a request header mapping for XmlHttpRequest. if your request is having this header, then JsonMediaTypeFormatter is always chosen. Formatters which are matched by media type mapping(here Json's RequestHeaderMapping) always trump the matches on Accept header. FYI: check this source code: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/XmlHttpRequestHeaderMapping.cs

Comment: @KiranChalla, oh wow, thanks. Not always though, XMLHttpRequests with correct `Accept` header get handled by my Formatter. So I'm wondering if there's a way to change that behaviour for "empty" Accept headers.

Comment: Hmm, i am actually not clear about your question. If you would want a specific media type in the response, you should specify it explicitly(`text\html`) and then also add the very generic media type(`*/*`) in the worst case of accept any kind of response media type from the service(Example: `Accept: text/html;*/*`). what did you mean my empty accept headers?

Comment: @KiranChalla, Accept header is optional and according to the source code link you provided `Accept` header with `*/*` is treated as an empty header. But basically my question is how to handle XMLHttpRequests with empty `Accept` headers by my custom Formatter.

Comment: Ok, sure. 1) If your request was a POST request and you did not have Accept header, then Web API tries to content-negotiate based on the Cotent-Type header.2) If your request was a GET request and did not have Accept header, then Web API tries to find out the first formatter in the list of formatters which can 'write` the response type. 3)Irrespective of GET or POST, if you implement a custom MediaTypeMapping and inspect the incoming request and say its a match, then your formatter is always chosen. This is what i meant by  match by MediaTypeMapping always wins.

Comment: Explaining the con-neg algorithm is exhaustive. You could probably take a look at my beginning 2 posts on content negotiation here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/. These posts were written long time back, but should still give good info.

Comment: @KiranChalla, alright, thank you for your help. I just started digging WebApi and I'm going to look at its lifecycle and MediaTypeMappings closely. Do you want to make your first comment an answer, so I can accept it and close the question?